# get_attachments( ) in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

What is the array format of get_attachments( ) function in woocommerce returns?.

```
$this->send($this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(),$this->get_attachments());
```

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump` it?

Comment: no, i don't know how to use var_dump in here because it is an email sending function.

Comment: Just add `var_dump($this->get_attachments());` before your line and look at the output (or log)

Comment: The output of this function is an email. we can't see the output of var_dump() there

Comment: Then send the output of the `var_dump` as the body of the mail to yourself

Comment: @dWinder Thank you...used your idea....nd got a solution , used print_r($this->get_attachments(), true )  as the body of the mail.

Comment: Great, glad to help. Please post you solution as answer to your question so other stack-overflower could use it

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Get email attachments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function get_attachments() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', array(), $this->id, $this->object );
}
```

It return an empty array if nothing added. Sample code snippet to add an attachment

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);

function conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments, $status , $order ) {
    $allowed_statuses = array( 'new_order',);
    if( isset( $status ) && in_array ( $status, $allowed_statuses ) ) {
        $your_pdf_path = get_template_directory() . '/terms.pdf';
        $attachments[] = $pdf_path;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```